# Preserving table content when dropping enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

According to the [Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#enumerated-types):

> There's no built in support for dropping enums, but you can do it
> manually. You should first drop any table that depends on them.

I'm writing a migration that adds an `enum` to an existing table. What's the best way to build such a migration? Is there any way to preserve the content of the table?

Answer (score 0):

Confused because you've linked to the place in the guide that shows how to add an enum. Nothing will happen to the rest of your table when you add an enum column.

Worth adding that you can use the Rails `enum` without having an enum type column in your database table, just make a string column (or integer) and set your `enum` up in your model and Rails will save the value to the DB. The Rails enum will prevent any other values being stored in that column, although obviously if you use SQL to insert values, either from your Rails app or from some other source, then your DB won't prevent other values being inserted.